# Is there an easy way to get to www.stackexchange.com from any of the SE sites?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, stack-exchange-button, navigation

One thing I've noticed about the relatively new sitewide layout is that I can't find a quick way to get back to www.stackexchange.com without finding StackExchange in the sites list. As a result, I am typing stackexchange in my toolbar a whole lot more often now. In particular, I tend to enjoy browsing the hot questions list and my own personal feed quite often so visit these pages on a daily basis. Is there an easy link to them that I'm missing?

(On the android app, there is a feed in the menu that I really appreciate, something like that on the desktop would be ideal!)

Comment: The "Hot Network Questions" text is a link to the full page of the hot questions. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh cool, didn't know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Stack Exchange button is a link to http://stackexchange.com, you can middle-click (new tab), right-click (context menu), <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click (new window) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click (new tab) on it. Shortcuts may or may not work depending on your browser.

Comment: If I normal click or middle click the menu just appears. Thanks for the right click tip!

Comment: Handy, but bad discoverability. That is where I would try to click. It looks like a typical logo/link combination. It even shows the hand cursor when hovering. But a click just open a menu. I use middleclicking a lot, yet I haven't discovered this feature until reading about it here. I just resorted to typing the URL each time.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Chrome.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Indeed, seems to be impossible on Chrome. I remember it working back then, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

On every page in every site, the "Hot Network Questions" text links to https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot just like you wanted:

> [image]

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 3):

Click on the **YOUR COMMUNITIES** text.

[image]

That will bring you to your user profile on SE, showing all your site accounts. Simply click on the SE logo to go to stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah, thanks. At least that's quicker than typing it into the menu bar.